# how to ajax post a form that includes fields in a dynamic table for which both rows and columns can be added dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post

Each cell has some field, text input, radio buttons or select.

Am I forced to name the fields in such a way so the names embody the row and column indexes? 
like "data[row][col]"?
It is kind of a hassle to dynamically create those field names when adding rows or columns to the table..

Can jQuery magic be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can, look here:

```
// This assumes that you've wrapped the form #myform around the input
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    $('#mytable tr').each(function(n, elem) {
        $('td', elem).each(function(m) {
            $('input:text, input:radio, textarea, select')
                .attr('name', 'data['+n+']['+m+']');
        });
    });

    // Do some validation or just let it submit :D
});
```

Here you go!

Comment: Nice!. I will try this approach

Comment: Worked great. One comment: Need to scope the inner most selector as well: $('input:text, input:radio, textarea, select', tdElem)

Answer (score 1):

of course jquery magic can be used! just name your cells what they are and include a hidden field with the id, for instance:

```
<tr>
    <td class="firstname"><input /></td>
    <td class="lastname"><input /></td>
    <td class="address"><input /></td>
    <td class="phone"><input /></td>
    ... 
    <td class="whatever">
        <input />
        <input type="hidden" class="itemId" value="[the id]" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

when you want to update a certain row, grab the row by doing something like

```
var row = $('tr').find('.itemId[value=' + id + ']');
// if you're in an event handler: 
var id = $(this).parents('tr').find('.itemId').val(); //gets you the id you want
```

now you can do things like:

```
var firstname = row.find('.firstname :input').val(); //etc..
```

compile them into a JSON object:

```
var data = {"itemId": id, "firstname": firstname, "lastname": lastname, ...etc };
```

and submit via `$.post()`, `$.ajax()` or `$.get()`. Easy!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how will I deal with dynamically added columns? How will the fields in those new cells be named?

Comment: whatever you want to name them. when you create them you know what they are, even though they're dynamic, right? people don't just create random dynamic data...

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a table with y columns and x rows. You can simply grab the cell data out of each one using the [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) and [`gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selectors. For example, to select the cells of the first column (exluding the 'header' cell) you can do:

```
$("#tableId td:gt(0):nth-child(1)").css("color", "red");
```

So to grab the form element values from each cell you can do something like this, using [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
var values = $("#tableId td:gt(0):nth-child(1) :input").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
alert(values);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Nunhk/3/