# Click event on button is trigged when submitting a form with enter

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

I have a form with two buttons, one `input[type=submit]` and one plain `button` which is the cancel button.

I have two event handlers, one bound to the `form` on `submit` and one bound to the `button` on `click`.

When I submit the form by pressing enter in an input the click event on the button fires (and before the submit event I might add), why is this?

This happens in both gecko and webkit.

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/q3JPR/

If you submit by pressing enter I want the submit event to trigger, not the click event.

Comment: This also happens to me, I've spent roughly an hour searching the whole web  and have not found any documentation for this behaviour, let me know if you found something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change your button to be `<input type="button"...` then your events will behave properly... here is the fiddle:

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3JPR/1/)

Comment: @NicklasA. Behaviour is described here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html -- buttons in forms submit by default and need to be carefully specified if that is not supposed to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I also found this solution. If you set the  type attribute to "button" `<button type="button">My Button</button>` it won't submit. I think not specifying the type by default sets it to submit. So you don't have to change the element to input.

Source: [Add regular button inside form that does not perform a submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617212/add-regular-button-inside-form-that-does-not-perform-a-submit)

Comment: Which answer were you building off of?