# Why a button is clicked when a form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, browser

Say, I have a form with a text input and a submit button.

If there are no buttons in the form, just submit event triggers, but if there is at least one button with no type attribute or with `type="submit"`, it clicks it too.

Now, when I enter something in the input and then press Enter, I see that both button click and form submit events are triggered.

**Example:**

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <button onclick="alert('submitted');">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I suppose the form clicks the button automatically on the form submit event.

I wonder the origins and the reason for such behavior?
Why do I need the button to be clicked when I submit the form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click event on button is trigged when submitting a form with enter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760030/click-event-on-button-is-trigged-when-submitting-a-form-with-enter)

Comment: It's not, I actually wonder about the reason, not about how to fix this behavior.

Comment: Read the second comment of the answer.

Comment: @SergeiBasharov do you have any more concerns on the subject? Feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html):

**[4.10.22.2 Implicit submission](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#implicit-submission)**

> If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key while a text field is focused implicitly submits the form), then doing so for a form whose default button has a defined activation behaviour must cause the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on that default button.

**[6.3 [synthetic click] Activation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#run-synthetic-click-activation-steps)**

> Certain elements in HTML have an activation behaviour, which means that the user can activate them. This triggers a sequence of events dependent on the activation mechanism, and normally culminating in a click event, as described below.
>
> The user agent should allow the user to manually trigger elements that have an activation behaviour, for instance using keyboard or voice input, or through mouse clicks. When the user triggers an element with a defined activation behaviour in a manner other than clicking it, the default action of the interaction event must be to run synthetic click activation steps on the element.

[See full script here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#run-synthetic-click-activation-steps)

---

So pressing `Enter` is processed as saying `submit` in your microphone (with a voice input device). Your browser should behave as if the user has clicked the button to process the click event attached functions properly and improve accessibility for those who can't use a mouse.

Comment: @SergeiBasharov is it clear enough for you or do you have any more questions?

Answer (score -3):

It actually doesn't automatically press the button, that isn't what's submitting the form. The form is being submitted because that's a default characteristic of text boxes - if you have focus in the text box, pressing the enter key will cause an attempt to submit the form.
This article goes into a deeper explanation: https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/01/enter-should-submit-forms-stop-messing-with-that/

EDIT: Actually, more specifically, a form will only submit on the enter key if:
1)A submit button exists in the form, or
2)The form only contains one text input

If neither of these conditions is true, then the enter key should not submit the form