# Bootstrap btn class stopping form submission

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Looking for some help. I'm trying to create my login in page for an app I'm creating at work and using Bootstrap to style.

The issue is that I cannot get my form to submit. While debugging, I have found that adding the Bootstrap btn class stops the form from submitting. If i remove it, everything works as should.

Below is a before and after.

**WORKING:**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1>Asset Performance Tool</h1>
            <p class="lead">Defining new ways to improve!!</p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li>Bootstrap v3.3.7</li>
                <li>jQuery v1.11.1</li>
            </ul>
            <br><br>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block login" onclick="">Login</a>

            <!-- Login -->
            <div class="container" style="display: none;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form method="post" action="">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="submit">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

**NOT WORKING:**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1>Asset Performance Tool</h1>
            <p class="lead">Defining new ways to improve!!</p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li>Bootstrap v3.3.7</li>
                <li>jQuery v1.11.1</li>
            </ul>
            <br><br>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block login" onclick="">Login</a>

            <!-- Login -->
            <div class="container" style="display: none;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form method="post" action="">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="submit">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

**PHP-CODE:**

```
<?php

include 'php-scripts/UserLogin.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $userSession = new UserLogin();
}
?>
```

I'm struggling to see the issue here, and wondering if any of you could help or may have seen something similar.

Comment: Can you give a link or a fiddle where we can see the issue please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is sending a post-back request due to the fact a  type element is being used but the type has not been set to "button".

**before:**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

**after:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

To:

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: same thing. If I remove the btn class works fine. Add it back in...nothing.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try changing

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-btn"> SUBMIT 
    </button>

# use jQuery and php #

$("#submit-btn").click(function() {
  if (isset)...........
}

# Create a js file #
# add jquery google api #
# write php isset funciton inside js file inside click function #
```

Comment: If you set the button as `type=button`, it won't submit the form...., read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617212/add-regular-button-inside-form-that-does-not-perform-a-submit

Comment: Still the same issue persists. The issue definitely resides with adding the btn class to the element.