# Update HTML form field selections to show a new calculated total before form submission

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

I can't find anything regarding this simple problem.

I'm trying to create an order page and allow the user to update the total of their order using a button (without having to submit the form). I'm calling an external JS file to make the necessary calcs based on the input selections made by the user, but when I click a "Calculate Total" button the form appears to submit and clears everything.

I'm confused as to how to define the form. Do you "POST" or "GET"? I'll eventually tie this to a PHP script on the action field, but I just want to do client-side updates for the order total so the user can see an updated total before they submit it.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="js/special_order_calcs.js"></script>
<form class="my_web_form" id="frmSpecialOrder" name="frmSpecialOrder" action="" method="">
  
   ... Here I do all my other fields definition, then ...
   
   ... Here is where the text box is created to store the calculated total ...
   Order Total $:&nbsp;</strong><input class="my_form_input_short" type="textbox" id="ordertotal" name="ordertotal" readonly>&nbsp;USD

    ... Here's where I'm trying to update the order total within the JS file when the Calculate Total button is clicked ...

    ot_final = qty1 + qty2 + qty3 + qty4 + ot_shipping_handling;
    document.getElementById('ordertotal').value = ot_final;
    // Set successful status
    return true();

   ... Here are the button definitions ...
<!-- Create buttons -->
<button type="input" class="standard-button" onclick="calculate_total()" class="standard-button">Calculate Total</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="standard-button">Submit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="reset" class="standard-button">Reset</button></p>
```

I verified the calculation works via Alerts, so my goals is when I click Calculate Total, I'm expecting the updated calculation to show up in the 'ordertotal' textbox on the form so the user can see a new value if they change quantities, etc. without submitting the form. I know a zillion product websites use this and I'm just trying to do something simple. Thanks.

Comment: You are not showing how you reference the code in your `special_order_calcs.js`. You return a `true()` function? Return your calculation result and assign it to your value.

Answer (score 1):

If I have not misunderstood, what you want to do is to calculate the total amount of an order. Well, to do that on the client side you don´t need a form because you don´t have to submit any data. Just get the input values, calculate the total price of the order and change the `textarea` value with [.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<button type="input">` in the Form, try using `<button type="button"`. Otherwise you will realize that by clicking on the button, it always refreshes your site, therefor deleting your previously input data.

For more info about how `button` behaves in a form, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617212/add-regular-button-inside-form-that-does-not-perform-a-submit) thread. The attribute `type` of the html-tag `button` has only three values: submit/reset/button.

If an invalid type is used, in your case `type="input"` it behaves like `type="submit"`, therefore submitting the form and refreshing the page

A tip from me: Use Console.log for error checking

So `console.log(ot_final);`, and afterwards:
`return document.getElementById('ordertotal').value = ot_final;`

`Console.log()` helps you find mistakes in your code way easier than using `alert()`. In this case `alert` fired of so you saw, that the result of the calculation was correct, but you didnt realize, that your site refreshed, after `alert()` was executed. Something that could have been prevented using `console.log`.